# Reading LAS file using lasio library doesn't handle "-" in datetime column

Tags: python, pandas, las

I have a las file and I am trying to read it in python using lasio library, one of the columns is `TIME` which is in the following format: `00:00:00.22-04-23`

Sample of data copied from `las` file:

```
TIME               col1 col2
00:00:00.22-06-23  1010  20
00:00:05.22-06-23  1020  25
00:00:10.22-06-23  1015  32
```

My code to read the data:

```
df = lasio.read(file_path).df().reset_index()
```

This returns the `df` in the following format:

```
TIME               col1 col2 UNKNOWN:1  UNKNOWN:2
00:00:00.22         -06 -23    1010       20
00:00:05.22         -06 -23    1020       25
00:00:10.22         -06 -23    1015       32
```

As you can see, my `TIME` column has been split into three columns at every `-`. The data from `col1` and `col2` have been shifted to `UNKNOWN:1` and `UNKNOWN:2` (probably these columns are created by lasio during reading). I need it to return the `TIME` column as in the original form and avoid shifting the values of `col1` and `col2`, so I can strip, split and manipulate `TIME` using pandas once it is read into a dataframe.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: I need to read the data into dataframe so I can use pandas to manipulate the columns as I need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use `pd.read_csv` with correct delimiter. For example:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('your_file.txt', sep=r"\s+", engine="python")
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                TIME  col1  col2
0  00:00:00.22-06-23  1010    20
1  00:00:05.22-06-23  1020    25
2  00:00:10.22-06-23  1015    32
```

---

EDIT: With updated file:

```py
import re
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

with open('your_file.txt', 'r') as f_in:
    data = re.sub(r'\A.*~A', '', f_in.read(), count=1, flags=re.S)
    df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep=r"\s+", engine="python")

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                TIME     col1  col2   col3
0  00:00:00.23-04-23  1977.47   160  160.5
```

Comment: This means I will need to change the extension of my las files to txt? Also, I will need to manually delete the header information on top of las file

Comment: @serdar_bay No, just change `your_file.txt` for your filename.

Comment: My file is las file and has lots of header info

Comment: @serdar_bay I suggest to post how your file looks into the question (with correct formatting, not all - only the relevant parts).

Comment: Please see sample of header, I only left the first row of data

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly well. Can you explain a bit your code!

Comment: @serdar_bay I remove the header (from the beginning of the file to the `~A` string) and then use `pd.read_csv` to read the rest to the dataframe.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253570/discussion-between-serdar-bay-and-andrej-kesely).